# Java generics Pair<String, String> stored in HashMap not retrieving key->value properly

Tags: java, string, generics, hashmap

Here's Pair.java

```
import java.lang.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class Pair<TYPEA, TYPEB> implements Comparable< Pair<TYPEA, TYPEB> > {
  protected final TYPEA Key_;
  protected final TYPEB Value_;

  public Pair(TYPEA key, TYPEB value) {
    Key_   = key;
    Value_ = value;
  }
  public TYPEA getKey() {
    return Key_;
  }
  public TYPEB getValue() {
    return Value_;
  }
  public String toString() {
    System.out.println("in toString()");
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
      buff.append("Key: ");
      buff.append(Key_);
      buff.append("\tValue: ");
      buff.append(Value_);
    return(buff.toString() );
  }
  public int compareTo( Pair<TYPEA, TYPEB> p1 ) { 
    System.out.println("in compareTo()");
    if ( null != p1 ) { 
      if ( p1.equals(this) ) { 
        return 0; 
      } else if ( p1.hashCode() > this.hashCode() ) { 
            return 1;
      } else if ( p1.hashCode() < this.hashCode() ) { 
        return -1;  
      }
    }
    return(-1);
  }
  public boolean equals( Pair<TYPEA, TYPEB> p1 ) { 
    System.out.println("in equals()");
    if ( null != p1 ) { 
      if ( p1.Key_.equals( this.Key_ ) && p1.Value_.equals( this.Value_ ) ) { 
        return(true);
      }
    }
    return(false);
  }
  public int hashCode() { 
    int hashCode = Key_.hashCode() + (31 * Value_.hashCode());
    System.out.println("in hashCode() [" + Integer.toString(hashCode) + "]");
    return(hashCode);
  }
}
```

Here's the testcase:

```
import java.lang.*; 
import java.util.*;

import junit.framework.*;

public class PairTest extends TestCase { 

  public void testPair() { 
    String key   = new String("key"); 
    String value = new String("asdf"); 

    Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<String, String>( key, value ); 

    assertTrue( pair.getKey().equals( key ) );
    assertTrue( pair.getValue().equals( value ) );
    assertTrue( pair.equals( new Pair<String, String>(key, value)) );
  }

  public void testPairCollection() { 

    HashMap< Pair<String, String>, String> hm1 = new HashMap<Pair<String,String>, String>(); 

    Pair<String, String> p1 = new Pair<String, String>("Test1", "Value1"); 
       hm1.put(p1, "ONE");  
    Pair<String, String> p2 = new Pair<String, String>("Test1", "Value2"); 
       hm1.put(p2, "TWO");  
    Pair<String, String> p3 = new Pair<String, String>("Test2", "Value1"); 
       hm1.put(p3, "THREE");    
    Pair<String, String> p4 = new Pair<String, String>("Test2", "Value2"); 
       hm1.put(p4, "FOUR"); 
    Pair<String, String> p5 = new Pair<String, String>("Test3", "Value1"); 
       hm1.put(p5, "FIVE"); 
    Pair<String, String> p6 = new Pair<String, String>("Test3", "Value2"); 
       hm1.put(p6, "SIX");  
    Pair<String, String> p7 = new Pair<String, String>("Test3", "Value3"); 
       hm1.put(p7, "SEVEN");    

    assertTrue( hm1.size() == 7 ); 

    Pair<String, String> pSrch = new Pair<String, String>("Test3", "Value3"); 
    assertTrue( p7.equals(pSrch) );
    assertTrue( pSrch.equals(p7) );
    assertTrue( p7.hashCode() == pSrch.hashCode() ); 
    assertTrue( 0 == p7.compareTo( pSrch ) );
    assertTrue( 0 == pSrch.compareTo(p7) );

    System.out.println("starting containsKey search");
    assertTrue( hm1.containsKey( p7 ) );
    System.out.println("starting containsKey search2");
    assertTrue( hm1.containsKey( pSrch ) );
    System.out.println("finishing containsKey search");

    String result = hm1.get( pSrch );
    assertTrue( null != result );
    assertTrue( 0 == result.compareTo("SEVEN"));

  } 
}
```

Here's my problem, the last hm1.containsKey call should (I naively expect) return the value stored where Pair<"Three", "Three"> is true - I should get a String with a value of "SEVEN".  Here is the output:

```
Running in equals()
in hashCode() [1976956095]
in hashCode() [1976956126]
in hashCode() [1976956096]
in hashCode() [1976956127]
in hashCode() [1976956097]
in hashCode() [1976956128]
in hashCode() [1976956159]
in equals()
in equals()
in hashCode() [1976956159]
in hashCode() [1976956159]
in compareTo()
in equals()
in compareTo()
in equals()
starting containsKey search
in hashCode() [1976956159]
starting containsKey search2
in hashCode() [1976956159]     <--- Bug here?

Never reaches 
          String result = hm1.get( pSrch );
```

So is both p7.hashCode() and pSrch.hashCode() are equal and p7.equals(pSrch) and pSrch.equals(p7), and hm1.containsValue(p7) == true, I would expect hm1.containsValue(pSrch) would also return true, but it does not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to *override* the `equals` method from the `java.lang.Object` class.

Instead, you've *overloaded* the method with an additional version that takes a `Pair`. Totally different method that never gets called. Replace your `equals` with something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) { 
  System.out.println("in equals()");
  if (o instanceof Pair) { 
    Pair<?, ?> p1 = (Pair<?, ?>) o;
    if ( p1.Key_.equals( this.Key_ ) && p1.Value_.equals( this.Value_ ) ) { 
      return(true);
    }
  }
  return(false);
}
```

To avoid this kind of mistake, use the `@Override` annotation on methods you intend to act as overrides. You'll get a compile time error when they don't.

Comment: Key_ and Value_ could be null. (Incorrect names, btw original questioner.)

Comment: I'm the original poster, I'm not sure I follow on the incorrect names bit?  That in equals() that p1.Key_ could be null?  Yes, correct.  Thanks for that.

Comment: You probably want to test if this.getClass() == o.getClass(), instead of merely instanceof, unless you really want a subclass of Pair to (possibly) be equal to an instance of Pair. This might lead to your equals() implementation not being reflexive - meaning it's possible for a.equals(b) != b.equals(a). This would violate the stated contract of Object.equals().

Comment: Or make the class, or at least the relevant methods, `final`. Classes have to be designed carefully for extensibility. This one is not (undocumented self-use of methods, undefined refinements to equals, etc). So the safest choice is to make it final. Composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

You should have noticed that it does not print "in equals()" after "starting containsKey search2". Also you could debug into HashMap to see that .equals() method is called and returns false. That's because

```
public boolean equals( Pair<TYPEA, TYPEB> p1 )
```

does NOT override

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

defined in java.lang.Object

Change your code to

```
  public boolean equals( Object obj ) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Pair)) return false;
    Pair p1 = (Pair) obj;
```

and it works. You can avoid such bugs in the future by putting @Override annotation before method that you think you are overriding. If you are not actually overriding it, compiler will tell you. This

```
@Override public boolean equals( Pair<TYPEA, TYPEB> p1 )
```

causes compilation error. This

```
@Override public boolean equals( Object obj )
```

does not. Also good IDE (Intellij IDEA for example) shows which methods are overriden.

Comment: I knew it was something simple - yet those calls to hashCode() came from the HashMap itself - I was considering it was fast-mapping via hashCode.