# Double table in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I need a double table from which I get two values from a key or index. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019177/java-double-entry-table) question already and I want to know what would be a better approach considering also performance.

1) Create a HashMap on this way:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> = ...;
```

I don't know how to put values inside this the put method, I have this and Eclipse gives me an error `prueba.put(0, new Hashtable<"Hi", "Bye">);` As you can see I have never used something like this before I am sure is a simple question.

2) Create a HashMap on this way:

```
HashMap<Integer, YourFancyDatatype>
```

So I create a class which pack the two or more values I want to have in one Object inside a single key or index.

Which would perform better ? Also if you can help me about how to use number 1) approach. The HashMap will have about 20000 entries.

Thank you very much for your time and help :)

Comment: In the first method you don't need: `HashMap<String, String>` - what you want to use is `String[]` (with size = 2)

Comment: Well, only the second approach even makes sense, so I'd go with that.

Comment: By the way, the question you cite is solving a different problem: namely, when there are two *keys* per value, not two *values* per key.  The `Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>` was thus meant to be used as `map.get(1).get("a")`.  Your situation is different.

Comment: Second method seems more logical. I would go with that.

Comment: @MarkPeters yes that is right but I thought in my case would be similar because for every key I get a HashMap<String, String> with the two values I want. Correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want something with a single key and a collection of values. I would suggest using [Apache's MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html), as they already implement this functionality for you.

Comment: Or Guava's `Multimap`, which actually uses Generics.

Comment: That works too (and is probably a better choice). My main point is that someone has already written this.

Comment: Thank you I will use Guava's Multimap is exactly what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach uses the same datastructure as provided by the Guava's [HashBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) so you can use it instead.

But if you want the best performance you could try to use something based on arrays (e.g. Guava's [ArrayTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html))

Anyway I suggest to make some simple performance tests to check which solution performs better.

Answer (score 0):

It you want to do an "in-line" put, you can do this:

```
prueba.put(0, new HashMap<String, String>() {{put("Hi", "Bye");}});
```

This employs an anonymous subclass of HashMap that has an instance block that loads the values.

Note that this will create one extra class for the JVM (called MyClass$1 or similar).

Comment: This is such an anti-pattern.  It creates a new class for every such insertion, just to save a line of code.  If you really need inline insertion, get a library that gives you a map builder (like `Guava`) or make one yourself.  It'll read better too.

Comment: @Mark no it doesn't. It creates just one new class for the JVM. People  says this is an anti-pattern like it's a travesty, but what's the big deal really? If you run out of permgen then I'd say, OK it's a problem, but most applications have 100's of classes - so you've got a few more.

Comment: by "for every such insertion", I mean every line of code that you do that.

Comment: Nice, and which would be a better approach without an "in-line" use?

Comment: @Andres: This is answering a question that you shouldn't be asking.  Using a `Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>` for your scenario is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to put values inside this the put method, I have this
>   and Eclipse gives me an error prueba.put(0, new Hashtable<"Hi",
>   "Bye">); As you can see I have never used something like this before I
>   am sure is a simple question.

Firstly, `Hashtable<String, String>` is not a subtype of `HashMap<String,String>`. your HashMap expects a `HashMap<String, String>` as a value. either insert a hashmap into values or change your hashmap declaration to :

```
HashMap<Integer, ? extends Map<String, String>> = ...;
```

however your 2nd approach is more object oriented. so i'd recommend using 2nd approach

Answer (score 0):

The second one would probably be easier in your case in this way

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, FancyDataType>> h= ...;
```

this is how you'll have to insert the data

```
 h=HashMap<Integer, FancyDataType>     new Hashtable<Integer,FancyDataType>();
numbers.put(0, new FancyDataType("o","x"));
numbers.put(1, new FancyDataType("t","y"));
numbers.put(1, new FancyDataType("q","z"));
/// ...so one for all 20000
```

Assuming FancyDataType is something like

```
class FancyDataType{
  String k,v;
  FancyDataType(String k,String v){
      this.k=k;this.v=v;

   }

}
```